# fatal error: rqt_gui_cpp/plugin.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to build PTAM on ROS : http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam but I'm getting the following error:

remote_ptam.h:38:32: fatal error: rqt_gui_cpp/plugin.h: No such file or directory

I checked and rqt_gui_cpp/plugin.h does exist under /opt/ros/kinetic/include.

I'm working with Ros Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Does anyone know what's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263951/fatal-error:-rqt_gui_cpp/plugin.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [houssem](https://answers.ros.org/users/30651/houssem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was mostly missing some package dependencies,
I updated it to build with kinetic and [made a pr](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam/pull/98/files).

You can try it out (I don't know if it works, I just made it build):

```
git clone -b kineticbuild https://github.com/lucasw/ethzasl_ptam.git
```

The changes are probably compatible with jade as well.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5